# Nativescript transparent actionbar

Tags: android, nativescript

I have searched StackOverflow see here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nativescript+transparent+actionbar but all the comments seem to be aimed at Nativescript IOS transparent Actionabar. I do not want to create a custom Actionabar I know I can do that; I just want to know how to make the stock Actionbar transparent but still make the text viewable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I originally wrote this on Angular but it can work with any flavor you will need to adjust the syntax accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" android:backgroundColor="transparent" (loaded)="onActionBarLoaded($event)" (layoutChanged)="onLayoutChanged($event)">
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout class="page" (loaded)="onLoaded($event)" [paddingTop]="fromTop">
    <Label class="h2" text="Hello!"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**TS**

```
    fromTop: number = 0;

    onLoaded(event: EventData) {
        const layout = <GridLayout>event.object,
            page = layout.page;

        if (page.android) {
            page.android.removeRowAt(0);
        }
    }

    onActionBarLoaded(event: EventData) {
        const actionBar = <ActionBar>event.object;
        if (actionBar.ios) {
            (<any>actionBar).updateFlatness = function (navBar) {
                actionBar.ios.setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIImage.new(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
                actionBar.ios.translucent = true;
            };
        }
    }

    onLayoutChanged(event: EventData) {
        const actionBar = <ActionBar>event.object;
        if (actionBar.android) {
            this.fromTop = layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(actionBar.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }
```

Use Core event binding syntax - for example `(loaded)="onLoaded($event)"` will become `loaded="{{ onLoaded }}"` and you will define the callback in view model. Similarly for property binding, define `fromTop` in View Model and bind it in XML.

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0rZCki&v=1)